# Can't bind event to dynamically created element

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, event-handling

I have following html structure in editstaff.php:

```
<div id="result" style="display:none">This is result div</div>
<form id="adres" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="adrs" />
<input type="submit" value="Address" /></form>
```

And in inline-style:

```
#result{
position: absolute;
border: 5px solid gray;
padding: 10px;
background: white;
width: 270px;
height: 190px;
}
```

What this html page do, clicking on "Address" button of "adres" form, some post data is send to another php page which shows information based on sent data on a pop-up like div (which style was display:none) fadeIn from display:none. The javascript/jquery codes for this purpose are as follows:

```
<script>
function submitForm(){
  var data=$("#adres").serializeArray();
  /* alert(data); */
  data.push(
  {
    name:'sname',value:$("#title").val()
  }
  );
  $.post("geteditdata.php",data,
  function(data){
    $("#result").html(data);
    positionPopup();
    $("#result").fadeIn(1000);

  }
 )
return false;
}
function positionPopup(){
$("#result").css({
left: ($(window).width() - $('#result').width()) / 2,
top: ($(window).width() - $('#result').width()) / 2,
position:'absolute'
});
}

$("#divclose").live('click',function(){
$("#result").fadeOut(500);
});


</script>
```

i.e the div in editstaff.php with fetched data will pop-up like following structure:

```
<div id="result">
some_value
<a href="#" id="divclose">Close</a>
</div>
```

All things is going on okay upto this stage. But when I am clicking on "Close" link on pop-up div the div is not closing(fadeOut) with $("#divclose").click(function()

Why this is not happening in this case?
can anybody give a solution for me?
I am giving a demo page where you can see the problem in practical.

1. Please visit http://raddacentre.org/editstaff.php and
2. write 'Afsar' in "Search by name" field and
3. then press "show".
4. After page loads, please press "Address" button which will be at the bottom of the page.
5. Then a pop-up div will be shown where there will be a link named "Close".
6. Press that button and please check why this div is not fade in there?

As I used jquery version 1.3, I used $("#divclose").live method instead of $(selector).on method.
Any help will be appreciated.

in geteditdata.php there is only this code:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['sname'];
?>
<br /><br /><a href="#" id="divclose">Close Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using really old jQuery 1.2.3 (it's not jq 1.3), I'm not sure if .live exist in that version. So two things:

1. Use new jQuery (I suggest 1.9)
2. Use .on instead of .live (read about it, syntax is a little bit different)

Code should look like that:

```
$("body").on('click', "#divclose", function(){
  $("#result").fadeOut(500);
});
```

Instead of "body" you can use other container that exist when event is being binded.

Comment: It is now working. Only has to add $(document).ready(function(){...........}); no matter whether it is body or another container at $(selector).on(...............